# Check 2 checkboxes with one click on dynamically made list of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes that go together. One is for a name the other is for a price. I need to check the one for price and the corresponding name one gets automatically checked.

Here is my code:

```
<input id="name1" name="name1" value="Option Name 1" type="checkbox">
<input id="price1" name="price1" value="125" type="checkbox">Option Name 1<br>

<input id="name2" name="name2" value="Option Name 2" type="checkbox">
<input id="price2" name="price2" value="150" type="checkbox">Option Name 2<br>

<input id="name3" name="name3" value="Option Name 3" type="checkbox">
<input id="price3" name="price3" value="175" type="checkbox">Option Name 3<br>
```

How can I do this with javascript? I could do it if it were only one set, but I don't know how I would do this without making a separate function for each one. This list of check boxes is created dynamical with PHP, so there will be more or less depending on the item in the database that is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably something like this?

Add class `name` and `price` for the checkboxes for easy detection. And using event deleagtion since you are dynamically appending the

```
$(document).on('change','.name, .price', function () { //provide a container selector instead of document.
    $(this).next('br').prevAll(':eq(1),:eq(0)').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVkbb/)**

if you dont want to add another class to the markup then use startswith selector, and for both way toggle.

```
$(document).on('change',':checkbox[id^=name],:checkbox[id^=price]', function () { //provide a container selector instead of document.
    $(this).nextUntil('br').andSelf().prev().andSelf().prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mrEe/)**

This just select the next available br

Comment: @DougSteinberg You are welcome. Do you not want to check name if proce is checked? or only one way is needed? Updated the second example with that one.

Comment: I'm going to use css to hide the name checkbox. This way the user only sees one checkbox, but the values from both get sent from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Give the price inputs a class of "price" or something similar, and give the name inputs a class of "name" or somthing similar.

Then bind the events using the class selector, and find the corresponding checkbox using `next('.price')` or `previous('.name')`

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a class to each input and it's easy from there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".name").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
             $(this).next().attr("checked","checked");   
        }else{
             $(this).next().removeAttr("checked");   
        }
    })
});
```

checkout jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/megarameno/BSYvE/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<br>` anymore, instead, wrap them in divs.  That way they can be recognized as a DOM group and your JS can be intelligent - no need for a bunch of event handlers!

This example uses jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/Nu8w9/2/.  It checks the whole row either way, which I think is what you want.  Interpreting your question literally, it would just be `$('.row').on('change input:nth-child(2)', function (e) { $(e.target).closest('.row').find('input:nth-child(1)')[0].checked = e.target.checked; });`